# How do you ignore known words in sscanf?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I'm trying to strip the data from a string, something like this:

```
char * fromSocket = "GET /test.html HTTP 1.0\n""Host: www.example.com\n""Client: 127.0.0.1:60000\n";
```

Where I know that, in this case "HTTP 1.0" "Host:" and "Client" and the semicolon between the client IP and the port will always be there. I'm trying to use a sscanf() like this:

```
sscanf(conString, "%s %s HTTP 1.0 Host: %s Client: %s:%s", com, loc, hos, cli, port);
```

But when I test the outputs using this:

```
printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", com, loc, hos, cli, port);
```

I get a bunch of NULLs. How do I ignore the specific words that I know will exist? I looked at some of the pages online, but I think the 1.0 throws the scanner off or whatever. Thanks!

Comment: You appear to be missing `[\r]\n` and the slash in `HTTP/1.0`. Use an HTTP parser!

Comment: why looking at conString when the data is in fromSocket?

Comment: for testing, be sure to check the returned value from the scanf function to determine how many of the conversions were successful.  I would suggest starting with just enough in the format string to acquire the first '%s',  then work forward from there until the problem is found.

Answer (score 4):

You just put those parts into your format string, and `sscanf` will assure they're present and accounted for, but won't read them into any variable. For example:

```
sscanf("GET /test.html HTTP 1.0\nHost: www.example.com\nClient: %16[^:]:%d\n", cli, port);
```

Also note that white-space (outside a scan-set) in a scanf format string is treated a bit differently from other characters--instead of matching the specified character, it will match an arbitrary amount of white space (so, for example, `"\n"` in the format string can match `" \t\v \r"` in the input data). As such, if you need to verify that the new-lines are really new-lines (and not other white-space) you need to change them to something like `%*[\n]`. If you do that, keep in mind that the norm for most network protocols is a "\r\n" sequence.

If your real question is how to allow (for example) the `www.example.com` to be an arbitrary string, and you want to assure there's a string there, but don't want to read it into a variable, then you can use a conversion with a `*` to read but prevent conversion, like: `%*s`:

```
sscanf("GET %*s HTTP 1.0\nHost: %*s\nClient: %16[^:]:%d\n", cli, port);
```

Comment: I'd like if I could read "GET", "/test.html", "www.example.com", the client IP, and the client port into another data structure, but even with removing the new line characters, I'm still having issues with actually reading in their values.






Edit: Never mind, you were right. It was another issue that I was having that was messing up my output. Thanks man!

Comment: @chux: Oops -- quite right. I use `scanf` rarely enough any more that I forgot that. Thanks for the reminder; I've edited accordingly.